# jquery - show div when another has a certain class

Tags: jquery

in a list, I have the divs with class rtin-thumb with display none, I want that when inside rtin-content there is a span badge.rtcl-badge-_top, the rtin-thumb is shown as display block

```
<div class="listing-list-each listing-list-each-1 rtcl-listing-item">
   <div class="rtin-item">
      <div class="rtin-thumb" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="rtin-content">
         <div class="rtcl-listing-badge-wrap"><span class="badge rtcl-badge-_top">Top</span></div>        
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="listing-list-each listing-list-each-1 rtcl-listing-item">
   <div class="rtin-item">
      <div class="rtin-thumb" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="rtin-content">
         <div class="rtcl-listing-badge-wrap"></div>        
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: I tried to do it by catching the sibling divs that contain a span with that class, and displaying rtin-thumb, but it does it on all items in the list in general

Comment: One idea is to select all `.rtcl-badge-_top` elements and loop through them. For [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) one, traverse up the DOM to the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `.rtin-item` element, [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the descendant `.rtin-thumb` element, and change its `display` property to "block".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment from @showdev into a functional snippet.

Make sure not to assign `display:none` within inline-style, but preferably within `<style>` tag at beginning.

```html
<style>
.rtin-thumb {
  display:none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
</style>
```

Try and Run code snippet:

```js
$(function() { // triggers when jQuery is loaded

  $(".rtin-item").each(function() { // loop
  
    $(".badge.rtcl-badge-_top")
      .parents(".rtin-item")
      .children(".rtin-thumb")
      .css("display", "block")
      
  });
  
});
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #eee;
}
.rtin-content {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #999;
}

.rtin-thumb {
  display:none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="listing-list-each listing-list-each-1 rtcl-listing-item">
     <div class="rtin-item">
        <div class="rtin-thumb"></div>
        <div class="rtin-content">
           <div class="rtcl-listing-badge-wrap">
             <span class="badge rtcl-badge-_top">Top</span>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-list-each listing-list-each-1 rtcl-listing-item">
     <div class="rtin-item">
        <div class="rtin-thumb"></div>
        <div class="rtin-content">
           <div class="rtcl-listing-badge-wrap">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```